# Geolocation in Windows Phone HTML App not working

Tags: html, geolocation, windows-phone-8

I'm developing html5 windows phone 8 application and I've run into problem: geolocation doesn't work for me. I have `WebBrowser.IsGeolocationEnabled` property set to true and in app manifest `ID_CAP_LOCATION` is also checked. Hovewer even with the geolocation code copy-pasted from various HTML5 learning portals I'm still getting an error telling that site doesn't have geolocation permission.
Thanks for any help

```
var watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(scrollMap, handleError);

    function scrollMap(position) {
        myLoc.setLatLng([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]);
    }

    function handleError(error) {
        myLoc.setLatLng([0, 0]);
    }
```

Comment: Did you set `IsScriptEnabled` to `true` in `WebBrowser` as well?

Comment: Yes, I've checked - js works, geolocation - doesn't :(

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I know that javascript is working because the error message is displayed using alert();

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but solved it by totally rewriting my code - simplifying it:

> var lng, lat;
>
> ```
>         function getLocation() {
>             if (navigator.geolocation) {
>                 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
>             }
>             else { alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser."); }
>         }
>         function showPosition(position) {
>            alert("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
>             "\nLongitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
>            lng = position.coords.longitude;
>            lat = position.coords.latitude;
>
>         }
> ```